# Восстановление ключа подписи

Tags: google-play, android, key

Сделал приложение для андроид, создал ключ, подписал и выложил в маркет. Потом слетела винда и, конечно, ключ для подписи был утерян, пришло время обновления, а новый апк файл не загружает из-за несоответствия ключей. Есть ли способ восстановить ключ по его отпечатку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увы, нет. Всё, что вам остаётся теперь — публиковать приложение с другим package name.

Comment: И даже из старого апк нельзя?

Comment: Нет, нельзя.